# Entity Framework Code-First: Migrate a database known only at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to migrate a database that is only known at runtime, which means that I cannot use the Package Manager Console to update the database. Also it's not just one, but many databases, but it is the same schema for all of them :)

I'm using Ninject to generate and inject the connection string on the `DbContext` object. The context constructor looks just like this:

```
public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities(string database) : base(database) { }
    /* Properties code omitted. */
}
```

The method to instantiate a context follows:

```
public MyEntities GetDatabase(string databaseName, string connectionString)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
    builder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;

    MyEntities context = this._kernel.Get<MyEntities>(new ConstructorArgument(
        "database", builder.ConnectionString));

    Database.SetInitializer<MyEntities>(
        new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyEntities, MyEntitiesMigrationConfiguration>("MyEntities"));

    return context;
}
```

When a context is retrieved the method creates a connection string and passes it as parameter to the constructor of `MyEntities`. Also I specify in the method the type of migration I want (in this case `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`).

The migration code follows:

```
public partial class MyAccountInMonth : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("AccountsInMonths", "MovementDebtMonth", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
        AlterColumn("AccountsInMonths", "MovementCreditMonth", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
        AlterColumn("AccountsInMonths", "BalanceMonth", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
        AlterColumn("AccountsInMonths", "MovementDebtAccumulated", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
        AlterColumn("AccountsInMonths", "MovementCreditAccumulated", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
        AlterColumn("AccountsInMonths", "BalanceAccumulated", c => c.Long(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down() { /* Code omitted */ }
}
```

When I run the application, the following error occurs:

```
Cannot find the object "AccountsInMonths" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

What the migration does is change the type of the column `AccountsInMonths` from `int` to `long`.

It is a migration error, because the stack trace has calls to it. At this moment I can only think that the problem can be permissions because the table exists. Other possibility is some kind of problem on the connection string. Please, anybody has a clue for this? Thanks in advance!

PS: if it is not clear I can add more information to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I Had the several issue. Here is the solution:

1) Make your `Configuration` as a public class:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContextClassHere>
```

2) Make your Seed() method as a public

2) Add anywhere the code below, this will apply the latest migration and updates your db:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.ContextType = typeof(YourContextClassHere);
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

// This will update the schema of the DB
migrator.Update();
// This will run Seed() method
configuration.Seed(new YourContextClassHere());
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! This problem arose when I was working on a project on my old company. Unfortunately I cannot try this approach you suggest, so I let it open to others who have the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

To migrate a database outside of Visual Studio and the Package Manager Console, use the accompanying **migrate.exe** tool that is located in the EntityFramework nuget package. It basically let you do the same migration from a command line.

Comment: Can I do that with SQL Azure databases?

Comment: Haven't tried. Yet. I would expect so since its just a variation on Sql Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Package Manager Console with `Update-Database`. It has a switch to specify connection string - either connection string itself (`$ConnectionString` and `$ConnectionProviderName`) or named one from config (`$ConnectionStringName`).

Or you can use `DbMigrator` class to handle it yourself in code (similar to what's actually `migrate.exe` doing).

Comment: for now it is a good solution because I'm in development stage. But if it happens in the future it can be unfeasible because there is 1 database for access (hope there are many people accessing). So, for example, for 1000 accesses there will be 1000 databases and your solution is not the best. But it is  a good suggestion for now :) Thanks!

Comment: @jmpcm I added a note about `DbMigrator` class to my answer, maybe that might help you to do that in a batch.